# Thumbnails in Chrome does not show up

Tags: google-chrome, browser, icons, thumbnails

[image: My Google Chrome's Home Page]

This is my Chrome's homepage. Whenever I start Chrome or open a new tab, this page appears.
The page thumbnails just does not show up. Although the page icons and titles are proper. I figured that this happens many times because of failed network connections. But my network is perfectly fine and I get one click access. Why is this happening? I tried re-installing Chrome, nothing happened. Help if anyone can.